# Break link to referenced database

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm working with two Access 2010 databases.  One is kept on our company file server and the second one is saved locally on several PC's.  I would like to store my VBA code in the network database and use that file as a reference library for the local copies.  However, with that configuration, the network file is locked for editing as long as the local copy is open.  Using VBA, is it possible to break the link between the two files without closing the local file?

In an attempt to find a workaround, I set up a test environment as follows:

1. Created two blank Access 2010 database files in **C:\DB Test\**

   - **Local DB.accdb**
   - **Network DB.accdb**
2. Added module **LocalCode** to **Local DB.accdb**
3. Added module **RemoteCode** to **Network DB.accdb**
4. Added a reference to **Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3** in **Local DB.accdb**
5. Added a reference to **C:\DB Test\Network DB.accdb** in **Local DB.accdb**

   - This reference added **Network DB** to the projects list of my VBA editor as though the file were open.
6. Added the following procedure to the **LocalCode** module in **Local DB.accdb**

```vb
Public Sub ClearDBReference()

    Dim DBFile As String
    Dim Proj   As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim Ref    As Access.Reference

    DBFile = "C:\DB Test\Network DB.accdb"

    For Each Ref In Application.References  
        If Ref.FullPath = DBFile Then

            ' Successfully removes the library
            ' reference to the network database
            Application.References.Remove Ref
            Exit For

        End If  
    Next

    For Each Proj In Application.VBE.VBProjects
        If Proj.FileName = DBFile Then  
            ' Run-time error '440': Method 'Remove'
            ' of object '_VBProjects' failed
            Application.VBE.VBProjects.Remove Proj

        End If

    Next

    Set Ref = Nothing
    Set Proj = Nothing
End Sub
```

When I executed `ClearDBReference`, it successully removed the library reference to **C:\DB Test\Network DB.accdb** but was unable to remove the project for **Network DB**.  It's as though there were a ghost link between the two files but I'm uncertain what is causing it or what to try next.

Comment: Thank you for a well formatted, good question. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Uncheck "open exclusive" under File>>Options>>Current Database maybe?

Comment: @enderland Thank you for the compliment.  I'm honored.

Comment: @ckuhn203 I did not see an "open exclusive" option under File>>Options>>Current Database.

Comment: What happens if you remove the VBA project reference first?

Comment: @MP24 I tried your suggestion and received the same error message shown in the code comments.

Comment: Did you try using `CurrentProject` instead of `Application`?

Comment: @MP24 I did not see a reference to `VBE` or `VBProjects` in the `CurrentProject` object.  However, it did contain a reference to `Application` but that is the same one shown in my code.  For example - `Debug.Print CurrentProject.Application Is Application` returns True.  Please let me know if I've misunderstood your suggestion or have not found the correct way to test it.

Comment: Using `CurrentProject` indeed does not work. Just checked that myself. In Excel, references belong to `ThisWorkbook`, but in Access to `Application`.

Comment: What happens if you use `...VbProjects(proj).Remove`

Comment: @MP24 I did not see a `Remove` method for `Application.VBE.VBProjects("Network DB")`.  As far as I can tell, that method is part of the `VBProjects` collection and not the individual `VBProject` objects.

Comment: Ok, the only other thing I've found is the fact that most examples on the internet remove VBA by removing components, not projects: see e.g. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx. I think then there will be no issue when opening your "clean" database.

Comment: @MP24 Using code from the site you linked, I tried removing the `RemoteCode` module in the network database from one of the local databases.  But, I received an error: `Method 'Remove' of object '_VBComponents' failed`.

Comment: It seems you can't really delete VBA modules from other databases. You can, however, delete VBA modules from the database running the VBA code.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure I understand your scenario, but it sounds like you're only referring to the Front-End (FE) app/database?

If so, you can create a stub app for local machines, which just copies the FE to the user's machine each time it's run, opens the real FE app, and then the stub app shuts.

That way the 'master' on the server is never locked. Of course, you wouldn't modify this file, you'd work on a dev copy, then replace the master on the server.

ps, the 'master' should be an accde file.

Comment: You've proposed a very creative idea.  Unfortunately, the project for this question was put on hold and I'm currently unable to perform any further testing.  When we resume the project, I'll see I can make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why both DB's can't sit on the server?

A slightly different scenario, but we always put the Front End and Backend on the server with accdb's - that way there's no issues that arrive from network dropouts. Also improves performance and removes the need to backup files on the local PC.

Comment: Unfortunately, what you're suggesting would not solve the root problem.  The front end file would still be locked for editing if anyone had it open.  And, it would have to be closed before any changes could be made.  What I'm after is a way to toggle the link between the local / network database.